# Getting error while replacing the dataframe value using numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am new to python here I have a data-frame

```
id    values
1      100
2      200
3      3600
4      3654
```

Now, Here I am trying to replace the values using the following way

```
file_name = file_name.loc[file_name['values'] == 3654,file_name['values'] ,3600]
```

Here the values are like ,

```
if 3654 is then replace it with 3600 otherwise keep it as it is.
```

So, I am getting this error,

```
only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

can any one help me with this ?

Comment: the `.loc` syntax with booleans, a comma after with a series, a comma with a value. All inside the square brackets. This makes absolutely. no. sense. at. all.

Comment: Check `np.where`

Comment: can u please let me know what I am doing wrong ?